# How to allow a website to ask for geolocation permissions on Microsoft Edge

Tags: permissions, geolocation, microsoft-edge

I'm developing a website that asks the user for their location after they sign in.

I made the mistake of removing the permissions for localhost within Edge on my local machine.

Now when I call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` inside the console

I get this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((p) => {console.log(p)}, (e) => {console.log(e)})
-------------------------
[object PositionError]: {code: 1, message: "This site doesn't have permission to ask for your location."}
code: 1
message: "This site doesn't have permission to ask for your location."

__proto__: Object
```

How do I "re-allow" the website "localhost" to have permission to ask for my location in Microsoft Edge?

[Link to question on Microsoft Support Community Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/how-to-allow-a-website-to-ask-for-geolocation/83fcc10e-accd-4d01-b952-a9e21bf634cb)

> There is a request for this question to be moved to either the MSDN or the TechNet forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your computer. Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10, try going to Settings (search from the Start menu in Windows) > Privacy > Location and choose apps that can use your precise location.

To manage permissions for all sites, select the three doted icon > Settings > Advanced > Manage permissions under Website permissions. More details, please check [change website permissions - Edge](https://microsoftedgetips.microsoft.com/en-us/3/45?source=menu).